# What happens if Stack Exchange doesn't let anyone down-vote a newbie who has a reputation less than five?

Tags: discussion, down-votes, new-users

I was thinking that Stack Exchange itself already has a smart system that filters the quality of a new question. Even the architecture of Stack Exchange is dependent on growing user networks. Then why doesn't Stack Exchange just stop the existing users from down-voting newbies who have less than five reputation? This current system seems like **cyber bullying**. The community can correct the newbie in many ways *by leaving comments, and editing the question in a proper way of redirecting him/her to the right place*. I feel then only a newbie will stay with Stack Exchange, especially in Stack Overflow. It's only my opinion. What's the community's opinion?

Comment: Bad things happen, that's what.

Answer (score 13):

I've thought about this. In many video games, you get a few seconds of immunity from attack once you start so that you can acclimate a bit, develop a strategy and then go for it.

But while Stack Overflow and sites like it share many characteristics with your favorite MMORPG, you already *have* an infinite amount of immunity while you acclimate a bit and develop a strategy - it's the time from when you first hit the site until you ultimately ask your first question. What we need to focus on is better and clearer hints to new users to tell them that certain things are important, and they should spend a bit of time examining them.

On a technical level, while we're getting pretty darn good at identifying questions that are likely to be in need of improvement before getting full visibility - voting is a very valuable signal that we simply can't let go of, *especially* when we're examining a post from a very new user, because there's only weak signal to go by otherwise.

It's not bullying, and that's something else we need to get better at communicating as new users experience our system. Whenever you introduce the concept of *negative* reputation, you have to be really careful. Look at most other reputation systems on the internet, you can "like" or just do nothing, or rate something on a scale of 1 - *n* - but you can't take away points.

Getting more hints to better set user's expectations while helping them to avoid common pitfalls is something we're currently working on. So no, no force field for 10 seconds after you spawn, but we are working on making sure anyone that's paying any attention is likely to have a good experience as a new user.

Comment: you aren't getting anywhere "good at identifying..." at the site asker is asking about - UX.SE, it doesn't have Triage (note migration notice at this question). Please avoid bragging about luxury features available only on the "main" site in the network (Triage, push from Hot Network Questions after 7 hours, dupehammers etc)

Comment: I know this is probably against  every rule in the communication rule-book but shouldn't we more clearly state what an SE site is **NOT**. So start the tour and have the new user sign-off on a bullet list of: not a forum, not facebook, not reddit, not Yahoo answers, not a social network, not a tutorial site, not a replacement for google/bing search.

Comment: @rene - didn't we kinda [try that already?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/128548/what-stack-overflow-is-not) (+10k link)

Comment: That is a daunting list @Oded .... there is not much left to be...

Comment: @rene - yep, one reason it was removed. But the fact is, we'd rather be defined what we **are** and not by what we are not.

Comment: WSOiN was never intended to be read as an article, though, @rene; each answer was supposed to be an individually-linkable, just-in-time, non-employee-curated addendum to the help center.

Comment: @gnat There's a _lot_ of stuff in place that determines what should automatically go to Triage, and dozens of knobs to turn to tweak it. While triage is not enabled on the network, that underlying logic _is_ there, and we **are** getting pretty good at it :) As the question was migrated here, I answered from a more general perspective.

Comment: Also, it would be _extremely_ irresponsible of us to enable all of this everywhere, there's still too many kinks to work out. As the OP did lead in with an allusion to quality heuristics, I don't find it at all out of bounds to address it. It wasn't meant to 'brag' as well as it's going, we simply _can't_ take voting (the strongest signal we have) out of it.

Comment: _irresponsibility hammer_, most respectable way to explain lack of trying. (Yawn) wake me up when you do someting (_anything_) for smaller sites

Answer (score 12):

> Then why doesn't Stack Exchange just stop the existing users from giving down votes for newbies who have less than five reputation?

Let's think for a moment about what that would mean. Newbies will never know that they are posting bad questions, as they will not be getting any feedback that the questions are bad. People who answer questions would no longer be able to tell immediately that a question is bad and therefore shouldn't click through to it and respond. Other newbies will never be able to tell good questions from bad, meaning they don't have examples of either to follow or learn from.

> This current system seems like **cyber bulling**

No, this system is about **quality** and **accountability** of the asker. That it may appear as "cyber bullying" to some is because so many sites have neither.

> The community can correct the newbie in many ways by leaving comments, and editing the question in a proper way of redirecting him/her to the right place

What will happen is that many newbies will start engaging in long arguments on comments and simply not notice the edits made. These are many newbies who are oblivious and that will not try to learn the ways here.

Comment: It is all true and easy said by an SE employee with over 100K rep here and plenty on SO. (and yes, this comment from yours truly, the second close vote reviewer all time over on SO) .... ;)

Comment: @rene - I too started with 1 rep ;)

Comment: Wait...what? No `update users set reputation = reputation * 10 where accountid = 1190;` ....